# Manually select details of stacked horizontal bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have this plot and want to :

1. manually select the order in which the questions on the Y axis (e.g., Session detail, etc) appear (i.e., I want session detail to be the 4th and not the 1st)
2. to manually select the order in which the variable appear in the bars (e.g., I want agree to be the 1st, etc)
3. manually deciding the colour for each variable (agree, disagree, etc) using HEX values.

[image]

I usually find answers on these issues easily online, but with stacked charts am having some difficulties.

This is the code

```
data_melted <- melt(Data, id.vars = "X")
View(data_melted)

ggplot(data = data_melted)+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = X, y = value, fill = variable),position="fill", stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1))+
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_grey() + theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the order you should convert the columns to factors and pick the order in there.

For colours use `scale_color_manual`. ie `scale_color_manual(values = c(Disagree="red",....)`